# Default language for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I believe what I'm trying to do is simple but I've been at it for hours and can't find the solution.
Basically I have a site that has 2 languages: English and French.

I would like that if the url has no language, it redirects to a page,
but if a language is specified in the url, redirect to that page.

For example

www.mysite.com -> goes to index.php?lg=en&page=$1

www.mysite.com/fr goes to index.php?lg=fr&page=$1

In my htaccess file I have this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^fr(.*)$ index.php?lg=fr&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lg=en&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT : The code I have supplied is kind of working... the only thing is that it doesn't load my CSS/JS anymore.. when I try to type the whole path of the CSS/JS file, it returns a page not found... I know the path is good because if I comment the first rewriteRule the files get loaded... I have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Is `RewriteEngine` directive set to `On` in your Apache configuration? If not, the first line in your .htaccess should turn it on explicitly(`RewriteEngine On` should be the first line in the .htaccess).

Also you don't really need the second rewrite rule, do you? If no `lg` parameter is supplied via `GET`, you can default it to en in your index.php script.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...Yes the ReWriteEngine is ON. And I do need the second rewrite rule because I can have other URL... for example : www.mysite.com/products/ipod and I need that to go redirect to index.php?lg=en&page=$1